# Unable to connect to azure cloud service?

Tags: azure

I have created an azure cloud service and published to it using Visual studio 2012. The cloud service consists of a worker and web role. I have enabled remote desktop and can see that both are running as expected.

I know the worker role is running because I can see its hitting my sql azure database.

However the web role doesn't seem to me able connect. Using chrome I get the error "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect". Same happens if I use Internet Explorer....

However If I log on to the box, and tried it using localhost, it all works? I can access my site. But if I attempt to connect to this server using another pc, I cant seem to get passed "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect..."

Any ideas on what I have done wrong?

Contents of my .csdef file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="SalahTimesAzureCloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <WorkerRole name="SalahTimesWorkerRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
  </WorkerRole>
  <WebRole name="Igss.SalahTimes.Web" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8080" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: Wheat [endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433020.aspx) have you configured for the webrole? What are public ports for these endpoints? At best, post here your service definition file (.csdef).

Comment: As per the comment above - check the endpoints. Also, have you tried enabling remote desktop on the role? You should do so and then you should be able to check the IIS settings.

PS. You're not doing something stupid like deploying a staging service but attempting to connect via the standard address? ;P

Comment: I have checked that web.config settings for the web role, and they all seem fine to me... I am defiantly not deploying to staging, its production...

Comment: I found the issue - endpoint is 8080...not sure why this is the default. I can now connect to the site at sitename.cloudapp.net:8080 and it all works... I will change this to 80 and see what happens.

Comment: What was the result after you changed to 80? Did it work?

Comment: Yes it worked once it was changed to 80